# porting to vs2005 from VC6

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-c++

i was getting an link error mfc42.lib cant be opened, while porting vc6 to vs2005,
i added the lib path form vc6 directory to vs2005 option,
but nw i am getting error

link2001 unresolved external symbol "unsigned int (__stdcall* ATL::gfunc()

Comment: I think mfc42.lib is there in SDK, correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's wise to mix VS2005 projects with VC6 libraries. It's hard to say what the actual problem is. What I do in such situations is make a new VS2005 project that resembles your original project with regards to settings (GUI/Console, ATL, MFC etc) and see which libraries will be picked up. Then change the translated VC6 project to match these.